# Trying to Entirely Fill a 5.5 x 8.5 Book Cover with Color

Tags: xetex, geometry, books, covers, pspicture

I am trying to entirely fill a 5.5'' x 8.5'' book cover with color.

But, there is a vertical white strip, which for some reason, I have not been able to fill.

Consider the code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[hmargin=0in,vmargin=0in,paperwidth=5.5in,paperheight=8.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{pstricks,psvectorian}
\definecolor{Blue}{RGB}{33,41,88}
\definecolor{Gold}{RGB}{228,168,73}

% Overlay Title
\newcommand{\mytitle}[1]% #1 = title
{\bgroup
  \Huge
  \sbox0{\parbox{\columnwidth}{\centering\textbf{\color{black}#1}}}%
  \sbox1{\parbox{\columnwidth}{\centering\textbf{\color{Gold}#1}}}%
  \usebox0\llap{\raisebox{1.37pt}{\usebox1}}
\egroup}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-6.985,0)(6.985,21.59)%
\renewcommand*{\psvectorianDefaultColor}{Gold}%
\psframe[fillcolor=Blue,fillstyle=solid](-6.985,0)(6.985,21.59)%
\psframe[linecolor=Blue](-6.985,0)(6.985,21.59)% draws frame.

\rput(0,15){\mytitle{My Book Cover}}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

which produces the output

[image]

I compile with `xelatex`

QUESTION: Can anyone see what I might be doing wrong? Perhaps there is a problem with my specifications when calling in the geometry package or in the way I am defining the `pspicture`?

Thank you.

Comment: unrelated but use boxes 0 and 2 not 0 and 1

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The `\sbox0` and `\sbox1`? For, when I change the 1 to a 2, I get black instead of gold.

Comment: never use odd numbered scratch registers for local assignments so sbox2 and usebox2

Comment: @DavidCarlisle As so:  `\sbox0{\parbox{\columnwidth}{\centering\textbf{\color{black}#1}}}%
  \sbox2{\parbox{\columnwidth}{\centering\textbf{\color{Gold}#1}}}%
  \usebox0\llap{\raisebox{1.37pt}{\usebox2}}` ?? (This does seem to work.)

Comment: Off topic, but printed covers are usually done on larger paper and cut to size.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Even those to be uploaded to Amazon as a 5.5 x 8.5 book?

Comment: Try `\psframe[fillcolor=Blue,fillstyle=solid](-8,0)(6.985,21.59)`

Comment: Or `\noindent\begin{pspicture} ,,,`

Comment: @SimonDispa Thank you. I'm still working on your first comment---which covers the white space well enough, though I'm trying to make a similar adjustment to the frame which seems to be putting an unwanted black line near the top and bottom when I make a similar adjustment for the frame.

Comment: Perhaps it is better to suppress the frame.

Comment: @SimonDispa Your `\noindent` suggestion seems to do the trick! Perhaps you will post this as an answer. Thanks again.

Comment: @SimonDispa As for suppressing the frame, I tried that; but the unwanted black lines still appear. I don't know why. In  any event, `\noindent` seems to be the simpler and best solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this code.

The `pspicture` environment starts a new (indented) paragraph.  To suppress  it add `\noindent` before.

[image: a]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[hmargin=0in,vmargin=0in,paperwidth=5.5in,paperheight=8.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{pstricks,psvectorian}
\definecolor{Blue}{RGB}{33,41,88}
\definecolor{Gold}{RGB}{228,168,73}

% Overlay Title
\newcommand{\mytitle}[1]% #1 = title
{\bgroup
    \Huge
    \sbox0{\parbox{\columnwidth}{\centering\textbf{\color{black}#1}}}%
    \sbox2{\parbox{\columnwidth}{\centering\textbf{\color{Gold}#1}}}%
    \usebox0\llap{\raisebox{1.37pt}{\usebox2}}
    \egroup}

\begin{document}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    
\noindent\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-6.985,0)(6.985,21.59)%
    \renewcommand*{\psvectorianDefaultColor}{Gold}%
    \noindent\psframe[fillcolor=Blue,fillstyle=solid](-6.985,0)(6.985,21.59)% changed <<<<<<
    \psframe[linecolor=Blue](-6.985,0)(6.985,21.59)% draws frame.   
    \rput(0,15){\mytitle{My Book Cover}}
    \end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Many thanks Simon Dispa.

Comment: If you have time, you may want to post the output as well, so that other viewers can see how nicely the answer works. Thanks again.

Comment: @mlchristians Done! Thank you for your feedback!!